# Intellij Empty R file

Tags: java, android, eclipse, intellij-idea

So, I know that Many other people have asked this question, but I couldn't find the answer I needed.
So, I'm a beginner in Android, and am learning.
I'm using Intellij and most tutorials online use eclipes.
So in the tutorials Eclipse auto creates the MyActivity.java with stuff like onOptionmenus and other stuff
But when I copy the code into Intellij, R.menu.main and other stuff related to the R file contains Errors, Obviously since I didn't create anything for Intellij to recognize. Its just that intellij didn't do what Eclipse did so I tried to copy it.

So This is my question..
Do I not have to write the onOptionmenu or onOptionsItemsSelected and stuff on the MyActiity.java, or MainActivity.java in Eclipse, for Intellij?

Also, is there a way to make Intellij show the actual R file? I heard that if I go into the

C:\Users\Myname.IntelliJIdea13\system\compiler\appname.integers\

and into some other folders inside, but I am unable to find annything in the folders and search I cannot find the R file. so, is there a way to make Intellij show it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is probably because you haven't copied over all of the needed resource files from eclipse. You should have probably created the project in Intellij if you wanted to develop in that IDE. Though I still recommend android studio (see the bottom of the answer). These methods are to do with the selection of the options menu, maybe you don't use this yet but they are good to have, hence why they are auto-generated. Make sure you copied across all the resource files and if you have, rebuild the project with Build->Rebuild.

I personally recommend taking a look at [Android studio](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html). An IDE based on Intellij IDEA and designated to developing Android applications. It is developed by the google android team and has already come a long way despite still being in beta. It is an excellent IDE to use for Android programming.

*-Thomas*

Comment: I have created by project in IDEA and I did not copy over from Eclipse. The thing is that I'm watching a tutorial online, but it uses eclipse and it has auto generated stuff from eclipse, which IDEA doesn't have. So I wanted to make sure if I needed to copy those, or IDEA handles with those without creating it.

Also for Android studio, I have been waiting almost an year now, I think?, for it to become v.1.0. Once then I'm planning to change to that.  it's currently 0.8 so hopefully just a bit more.